# What is the best way to ensure that thousands of httprequests run on a schedule in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

We are developing a website health module that will require that we run a scheduler that will perform a http request per website every 2 minutes (but we also imagine each website has it's own interval)

Now, I'm having trouble finding the way to perform this task specially due to scalability.

I think we need to have a scheduled function per website that will run on its own and therefore rely on the Scheduler API to create thousands of schedulers but I don't even know if Azure allows so many schedulers...

Any thought on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I just checked the possibility of having a queue with delayed messages which sounds that it can do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

One option is to have 2 Functions:

- Timer triggered Function which would run every 2 minutes and would send a batch (or many batches) or messages to a queue or event hub, mentioning a URL in the body
- Queue (or event hub) triggered Function which would actually do an HTTP request and record/process the response

You could also use Service Bus trigger function with messages [scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet) for specific time, thus planning the schedule well ahead.